# Xcode 7 taking long time to generate build. Its almost stuck in Organizer window

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, xcode7

We've upgraded Xcode 6.x to 7.x and for every first build after system restarts, its taking more than an hour to spit out the ipa build. and from next time onwards it's fine.

Comment: This is a very opinionated question. Information provided is not enough. There are infinite possibilities as to why this is happening. Hardware, memory limitation, amount of code, disk usage or clean up etc.

Comment: Processor : 2.8 GHz core i5, 
Memory  : 8GB 1867 MHz DDR3, 
Total app size : 165MB, 
ipa size : 39.29 MB

Comment: anyone has any idea why its happening liike this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

uninstalled Xcode 7 and installed Xcode 7.2.x. now its working fine... so it seems that there are bugs in 7.

> It's not just about uninstall and fresh installation. Please follow
>   the below steps to stop hanging your Organizer window while taking
>   build.

1. **Delete all derived data ( ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData )**
2. **Delete all archives ( ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives )**
3. **Delete all products ( ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/Products )**

Then take the build .

> Note: All 3 steps are must to make the build faster